# Lollipop: Had trouble showing a shadow under the overflow menu

Tags: android, toolbar, shadow

I had some trouble getting the shadow to show in a certain `Activity` on Lollipop devices.

Despite the theme of the `Activity` and the Support `Toolbar` used was exactly the same as it was in any other activities. I was confused why I couldn't get the shadow to show in that particular `Activity`

I spent an hour or two trying to figure out the reason behind this. I hope that this will save someone else's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that `android:hardwareAccelerated` option needs to be `true` if shadows are to be rendered in Lollipop devices. Note that setting the flag isn't necessary as it's the default option for 4.0 devices (API Level 14) and higher. It's available on Android 3.X but is disabled by default.

Example follows:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

or more simply

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```